# Magento Cart Rule BUG - Wrongly applied when "less than" and configurable product

Tags: magento, configurable-product, product-quantity, cart-rules

I just found out that Magento seems to have a bug since 1.8 relating to cart rules.

let's say we have some configurable products and want to add a "discount" for a specific product if the qty is less then 50. In my case it a surcharge not a discount (you can easily add negative discount so it'll get surcharge by changing two files see http://php.quicoto.com/extra-fee-shopping-cart-price-rules-magento/).

so what does magento do?

1) checks if rule is valid for that product
2) if not it checks if it is a configurable product, then takes the first simple product, and check the rule against that.

in this case true cause qty is less then 50 ( cause this simple product is not even in cart.... )

extending the rule by a "less then 50 and more then 1" didn't worked.

```
    $product = $object->getProduct();
    if (!($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($object->getProductId());
    } 
    // here, everythign correct. $valid is false cause item is less then x times in cart..
    $valid = parent::validate($object);  



// this part makes no sense, cause he's checking on a child which is not in cart.
     /** /
     if (!$valid && $product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $children = $object->getChildren();
        $valid = $children && $this->validate($children[0]);
    }/**/
```

this small snippet is related to it, and in my eyes it doesn't make any sense. why the rule should be checked against the first product of a configurable one? why randomly check the rule against some other product?

does anyone has an idea about that?

my solution for now, just comment this line out ... ;-) and the rule get applied as it should.

greets
felix

[here's an image about the rule in magento backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/938ma.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$object` is instance of `Mage_Sales_Quote_Item`. If so, it explains why rule is being checked against first child - because it is **the only** child of configurable product in cart. It can't be more than one child of particular configurable product item in the cart at the same time

Comment: Sorry buddy, didn't get that at all.. :-) $object is the item in cart which get's validated first, and the variable $valid will be set to false. Like this it is correct... 

But then cause $valid is false it goes in the statement i mentioned above and just get's the first item of the configurable it finds ( $children[0] ) which has no relation to the one in cart. 

I also checked that with two configurations in cart of the same configurable product. Works fine. No need for that check.

Comment: If you look at sales_flat_[order/quote]_item table(s), you'll see 'parent_id' column. In case of bundle products we can see 1+ children (because this product type allows purchase 1+ 'components' (products, in fact) within one bundle). In case of configurable product you'll see strict one-to-one relation - configurable_item-simple_child_item. There is no need to search for 2nd, 3rd etc children because they do not exist - you may add to cart only one simple product along with its' parent - configurable item.

Comment: So, generally, sentense '$children[0] has no relation to any item in cart' is wrong - it has relation to the particular simple product ('option' of configurable product) you've chosen before adding product to cart. If you have configurable product 'T-shirt' and 3 simple (children) - green, yellow, white - and decided to add white T-shirt to cart - $children[0] will correspond to white T-shirt